# How to clear stdout line in Lua?

Tags: lua

You have a lua function that emulates progress completion in % writing to `stdout`.

```
function progress(completed)
  io.write(completed.."\r")
  io.flush()
end

progress("1% completed"); progress("50% completed")
```

The output gonna be

> % completed

Part of the text disappeared. In **python** in analogous situation I'd probably clear the line before writing to `stdout` the following way:

```
sys.stdout.write(' ' * 50 + '\r')
sys.stdout.write(text + '\r')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

How to clear `stdout` line in lua?

I'd do the following but is there a better or a more standard way?

```
function iop(str)
  io.write(string.format("%050s\r", ' '))
  io.write(str)
  io.flush()
end
```

Comment: The first script you have given is working as intended in Lua 5.3.3. The problem would start if second string was shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local last_str = ''

function iop(str)
   io.write(('\b \b'):rep(#last_str))  -- erase old line
   io.write(str)                       -- write new line
   io.flush()
   last_str = str
end
```

Now let's test it:

```
function wait(msec)
   local t = os.clock()
   repeat
   until os.clock() > t + msec * 1e-3
end

iop('Very very very long string')
wait(500)
for i = 0, 100 do
   iop(i..'% completed')
   wait(20)  -- wait 20 ms
end
print'\nDone'
```